# What UML relation should I use between these two classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, class-diagram

I have a class called "EventManager" and one called "Event". From Eventmanager I can created and store events in a linkedlisted, which then is stored in a hashmap together with "persons" who attend these events. Now, which relationship(UML) between Event and Eventmanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an HAS-A. Since EventManager contains Events.

Comment: Has-a, is it that one with a "diamond" at the end? I put the side with the end with the "diamond" next to EventManager. I also added a "*", because EventManager can have several Events, is this right? or?

Comment: Yes, and in this case i guess the diamond it's not filled since the event can still exist without the event manager (although you can't control this in java thanks to garbage collector, this filled diamond is important for languages like C++)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple association. EventManager is not composed of Events. It only provide list of events to process. Another association would be created between event and person.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is HAS-A relationship as EventManager class has Event class as its data member.

Simple association will not suffice in this case.